# CouchDB: Group data by key

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have following data in my database:

```
|  value1  |  value2  |
|----------+----------|
|     1    |    a     |
|     1    |    b     |
|     2    |    a     |
|     3    |    c     |
|     3    |    d     |
|----------+----------|
```

What I want as a output is `{"key":1,"value":[a,b]},{"key":2,"value":[a]},{"key":3,"value":[c,d]}`

I wrote this map function (but not quiet sure if this is correct)

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.value1,doc.value2);
}
```

...but I am missing the reduce-function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How exactly is the doc structure in your db?

Comment: A document looks like this: `{
   "_id": "239511c8efc7f28b1a78b0831ea6f2f5",
   "_rev": "1-f355c3d5c3aaea78e4de4094209ba544",
   "pedid": 0,
   "groupid": 0
}`

I want to group by `groupid`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can/should be done with a reduce function.

However, you can reformat the output with [lists](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later). Try the following list function:

```
function (head, req) {
    var row,
        returnObj = {};
    while (row = getRow()) {
        if(returnObj[row.key]){
            returnObj[row.key].push(row.value);
        }else{
            returnObj[row.key] = [row.value];
        }
    }
    send(JSON.stringify(returnObj));
};
```

The output should look like this:

```
{
  1: [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  2: [
    "a"
  ],
  3: [
    "c",
    "d"
  ]
}
```

Hope that helps.